# Can't connect to VPN using home Wi-Fi

Tags: wireless-networking, vpn

I just installed a new Wi-Fi yesterday, connect to VPN via mobile phone (I use 1.1.1.1 VPN) and it worked fine until today.

Later I found out that my provider has banned PPTP VPN type and now I can't connect to the VPN while using Wi-Fi but it works fine when I'm using mobile data.

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is really dependent on your provider, but the short answer is "use a protocol that they can't block."

It is a bit weird that your provider would block PPTP, but that may not be a bad thing - PPTP as a VPN is broken - the protocol has not been secure for many years.  That said, I do wonder if your provider has banned PPTP, or if it has simply been broken because your carrier is using Carrier Grade NAT.

Most people using VPNs would use one of IPSEC (mainly businesses), or OpenVPN or Wireguard.   If your ISP is playing silly buggers with your traffic, I'd recommend using OpenVPN.  The best protocol to use, of-course, is the default UDP one on 1193 - however if your ISP is deliberately blocking it, find a provider that will support you running this across an alternative port - TCP on port 443 will likely get across as very few providers would block that as its needed for HTTPS - and as HTTPS is end-to-end encrypted they can't intercept it without people noticing (and unless you have a dictatorial government) and jumping up and down.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to call your supplier and ask them to revert the changes they made. IF they decline you can simply state that you need to use a VPN for your current job. Let me know how you get on.

Comment: Per the question - the supplier did not make changes.- the client setup is new.  Most likely this is not a ban, its a limitation of the providers network. https://forum.mikrotik.com/viewtopic.php?p=830917 explains the problem.